# x509 Client Authentication to SAP Web Service

Tags: web-services, x509, sap-erp

We have an ECC 6 (Netweaver 7.0) system for which we are trying to establish x509 authentication to an ABAP web service. We’ve been attempting to follow the guide at: https://help.sap.com/saphelp_nwpi71/helpdata/en/a8/d9d53a9aa9e933e10000000a114084/content.htm.

Our end goal is to call the web service from a .NET client, but at the moment we can't even access the endpoint directly from a web browser (where I would consider a 500 error a victory).

In SOAMANAGER, the endpoint is configured for HTTPS and x509 HTTP Authentication. We are not using Message Authentication.The certificates are issued by a local CA, which we have imported into both the SSL Server and System PSEs, and the browser displays a valid SSL connection. The server prompts for the client certificate, which we can select. Users are mapped to their certificates from view VUSREXTID.  When navigating in a browser to the endpoint or the WSDL, we are prompted for a certificate and then receive a 401 error.

The ICM log does not display any SSL errors, but does show an SSL handshake and a "successful" user mapping. I'm happy to provide more detail if needed.

Any ideas why our authentication might still be failing?

Comment: no, but you could also check  transaction SRT_UTIL for more info

Comment: As far as I know, SRT\_UTIL is available from 7.1 forward, and we're on NW 7.0. Thanks for the suggestion, though!